# Sort date with dd-mm-yyyy format in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, datatables

I have a column "Availability" which has date format dd-mm-yyyy.

When I sort it ascending and descending it only works in Firefox. On other browsers specifically IE it does not work. However, if I use date format yyyy-mm-dd it works fine everywhere.

So, I looked around and found a solution as to create a hidden column with date format yyyy-mm-dd, and point my ascending and descending to that hidden column.

Unfortunately being novice with `data-tables` and `jQuery`, I am struggling with that part. To make matters more difficult, I have a huge filter with 25 filters, which are working on the hidden columns.

Here is my table head:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="15%">Username</th>   
    <th style="display:none;">Primary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Primary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Primary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Primary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Primary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Secondary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Secondary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Secondary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Secondary modules</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Secondary modules</th>
    <th width="20%">Primary Role</th>
    <th width="20%">Secondary Role</th>
    <th width="20%">Location</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Experience</th>                        
    <th width="2%"><?php echo get_currencysymbol($currencyid) ?></th>
    <th width="2%">Rate Type</th>
    <th width="7%">Availability</th>
    <th style="display:none;">sortable date</th>
    <th width="14%">Languages</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Languages</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Languages</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Nationality</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Nationality</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Nationality</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Nationality</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Nationality</th>                        
</tr>
</thead>
```

and this is my jquery

```
$('#dt3').dataTable()
    .columnFilter({aoColumns: [
        {sSelector: "#username"},
        {sSelector: "#pmodules", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#pmodules2", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#pmodules3", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#pmodules4", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#pmodules5", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#smodules", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#smodules2", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#smodules3", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#smodules4", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#smodules5", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#primaryrole", type: "select", values: [<?php echo addSingleQuotes($jobtitiles); ?>]},
        {sSelector: "#secondaryrole", type: "select", values: [<?php echo addSingleQuotes($jobtitiles); ?>]},
        {sSelector: "#location"}, /*LOCATION PART OF THE DISPLAY TABLE BUT NOT PART OF THE SEARCH CRITERIA */
        {sSelector: "#experience", type: "number-range"},
        {sSelector: "#rate", type: "number-range"},
        {sSelector: "#ratetype", type: "select", values: [<?php echo addSingleQuotes($ratetypes); ?>]},
        {sSelector: "#availability", type: "date-range", sType: "uk_date" },
        {},
        {sSelector: "#languages", type: "select", values: [<?php echo addSingleQuotes($languages); ?>]},
        {sSelector: "#languages1", type: "select", values: [<?php echo addSingleQuotes($languages); ?>]},
        {sSelector: "#languages2", type: "select", values: [<?php echo addSingleQuotes($languages); ?>]},
        {sSelector: "#nationality", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#nationality1", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#nationality2", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#nationality3", type: "text", bSmart: true},
        {sSelector: "#nationality4", type: "text", bSmart: true},
    ]}
);
```

How can I point my Availability to sort on the hidden column `sortable date`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [iDataSort](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#iDataSort) option.

```
$('#dt3').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "iDataSort": 1} // your display date
      { "bVisible": false }, // your behind the scenes date value to sort by
    ]
  });
```

I'm sorry, I don't have my own code accessible at the moment but I believe when you create the column you can specify the index on another (hidden) column to sort with. I use this for sorting US and UK dates.

Comment: i am trying to do the same, but for some reason i havnt been able to point to the hidden colum.

Answer (score 0):

Add this above your dataTable call:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
        var ukDatea = a.split('/');
        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },

        "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

        "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

Add this to your `aoColumns` that require UK formatted sorting: `{ "sType": "date-uk" }`

Answer (score 0):

Hello worked this way below. Should you wish to order fields of type date in jquery datatable plugin:

```
// Function to convert the date to be able to order
 jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
                    "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
                        var ukDatea = a.split('/');
                      console.log(ukDatea);  
                      return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]*1);
                    },

                    "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
                        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
                    },

                    "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
                        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
                    }
                } );



      // ordering the table by table field
      $('#table_id').dataTable({
           "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]] // 0 = date of position in your table
      });
```